# Outlook web add-in: event "RecipientsChanged" not working outlook on MAC

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on a office web add-in project, we have used the addHandlerAsync method to register the event in the add-in, 
here is how we use the event

```js
Office.initialize = function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
 Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged, itemChanged, function (result) {
                    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                        $("#testMessage").html("failed");
                        Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync("errorMessage", {
                            type: "errorMessage",
                            message: "callbackFailed"
                        });
                    }
                });
}
}
```

here is the callback method, just show the event called times on the html

```js
var i = 0;
        function itemChanged(eventArgs) {
            i = i + 1;
            // Update UI based on the new current item
            $("#testMessage").html("event"+i);
            //UpdateTaskPaneUI(Office.context.mailbox.item);
        }
```

The test result from outlook client on windows shows the event called event time when I change the TO or CC in the outlook, **but for outlook client on MAC the event could register successfully, but the callback can not be called**.

Is this an bug for office.js?
or maybe i'm using wrong method on MAC?
Any help will be appreciate.

Version of MAC system is 10.14.2

Outloook client version on MAC version is 16.20 (181208)

License: Office 365 Subscription

Here are the requirement sets supported by outlook on MAC
1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7

Thanks

### Product

Outlook, Outlook On MAC

Comment: API version 1.7 is not available for Mac as of now. 1.7 will be available for Users by early Q2. The Outlook API docs will be corrected soon to reflect this change.

Comment: Hi @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility, thanks for your reply, i have added my comment blow, please take a look, really appreciate for you reply.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook for Mac does not yet support the 1.7 requirement set. The documentation that mentions this is incorrect, and will be updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know the timeline when this would be supported?  We are very much in need in a project for a large customer. :-)